# How to center a PopupPanel

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In a web app built in [google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), I want to show a popup containing som text and links.
I figured that [PopupPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/popup-panel) is the way to go. This is what I've done:

```
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var popup = app.createPopupPanel()
  .setAnimationEnabled(true)
  .setModal(true)
  .setGlassEnabled(true)
  .setAutoHideEnabled(true);

  popup.add(app.createLabel('text text text'));

  popup.setPopupPosition(100, 100);
  popup.setHeight('300px');
  popup.setWidth('500px');

  popup.show();
```

But instead of setting a fixed position, I would like to center the box in the current window. Since there seems to be no such functionality, I tried to get the pixel size of the window, or form app, or a panel sized to 100%, but I can't get a size from anywhere, there seems only to be possible to set the size.

Is there a way to center the `PopupPanel`, or to create a popup some other way, that will be centered?

Comment: Not quite an answer, but I find this odd, as 'auto' should be an acceptable style attribute, and you SHOULD be able to set this using '.setStyleAttributes({margin: 'auto'})', but you can't, so I've opened an issue for it at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4548, and I'm curious to see what they say. Please star it if you think it would help resolve your issue.

Comment: awesome! thank you for doing that!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing what I want. Not the most beautiful solution, but it works.

```
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var popup = app.createPopupPanel()
  .setAnimationEnabled(true)
  .setModal(true)
  .setGlassEnabled(true)
  .setAutoHideEnabled(true);

  popup.add(app.createLabel('text text text'));

  popup.show();

  popup.setStyleAttribute('position', 'fixed');
  popup.setStyleAttribute('top', '100px');
  popup.setStyleAttribute('left', '25%');
  popup.setStyleAttribute('width', '50%');
```

It's important to set the style attributes after `.show()` since that call will set `position: absolute`, `top: 0` and `left: 0`